# What does a gift from Ormagöden do?

Tags: brutal-legend

In between missions you can find serpent statues who are covered in some leather. For each ten statues you free from their wrapping you get a *gift from Ormagöden*.

I freed my first ten statues and didn't get any hint as to what I got. What is this gift from Ormagöden? Is it always the same? Or are there twelve different gifts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For each bound serpent you free, you get the obvious 5 fire tributes that can be spent at Motor Forges.

For each 10 bound serpents you free, [you get a small boost to some aspect of combat](http://brutallegend.wikia.com/wiki/Bound_Serpent).

> ```
> 10    Increase your health a small amount. (10% above normal)
> 20    Increase your health regeneration a small amount. (10% above normal)
> 30    A small healing bonus for nearby troops. (5% bonus)
> 40    Increase your flight speed a small amount. (10% above normal)
> 50    Increase your health a large amount. (20% above normal)
> 60    Increase your health regeneration a large amount. (20% above normal)
> 70    A large healing bonus for nearby troops. (10% above normal)
> 80    Increase your flight speed a large amount. (20% above normal)
> 90    Increase your health a brütal amount. (30% above normal)
> 100   A brütal healing bonus for nearby troops. (15% above normal)
> 110   Increase your health regeneration a brütal amount. (30% above normal)
> 120   Increase your flight speed a brütal amount. (30% above normal)
> ```

It should be noted that these are the cumulative effects to the given aspect and are not additive for the boost affected - the 10% health boost is replaced by the 20% and then 30% and are not added on top of each other. In other words, each health boost, regen boost, and flight boost adds 10% more to the bonus over default behaviour, and each troop regen boost adds 5%.

You get all these same 12 gifts in the same order every time you play through the game.

They also count towards game progress for achievements such as the 100% completion achievement, Metal God.